# Facebook Offline Publish Stream to wall asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using facebook graph API to get the loged in user token http://www.mattcashatt.com/facebook_code.htm

Also, I am grabbing these facebook params "publish_stream,email,offline_access" when any user logs into my website.

If i have 100 uses who logged into my website, How can i post an offline message onto their wall and if possible to their friends wall too.

Please let me if this can be done ? Any code examples will be great.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this code to Post Publish from this link
http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Examples&referringTitle=Documentation

Post Publish:

```
var client = new FacebookClient("my_access_token");
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = "Check out this funny article";
parameters.link = "http://www.example.com/article.html";
parameters.picture = "http://www.example.com/article-thumbnail.jpg";
parameters.name = "Article Title";
parameters.caption = "Caption for the link";
parameters.description = "Longer description of the link";
parameters.actions = new {
    name = "View on Zombo",
    link = "http://www.zombo.com",
};
parameters.privacy = new {
    value = "ALL_FRIENDS",
};
parameters.targeting = new {
    countries = "US",
    regions = "6,53",
    locales = "6",
};
dynamic result = client.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view my post on facebook developer forums:

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=78818